# include file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to include file detect_simple.py, but it doesn't work.

Capture screnshoot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/usqBy.jpg

My code: in file app.py

```
__import__("Face_recognition/detect_simple")
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "OK";
@app.route('/api1')
def api1():
    return "OK"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
run command: python app.py

return error: `Import by filename is not supported.`
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `__import__`? Is that a file you are trying to open?

Comment: Did `Face_recognition/detect_simple` is in your app project folders ?

Comment: I think you want the answer from Jab below. That being said anything with leading and ending double under scores (i.e. `__str__` or `__import__`) in python is a magic method or private hidden variables. More likely that not, it is something you probably weren't looking for. When you get familiar with the language they can be useful but for now if you are using it and you don't understand why, then you probably aren't using the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for instance if your `app.py` is in the top directory and you need to import a module thats in a folder below that directory just use the `from subfolder import mymodule`.

For example if your directory looks like this:

```
- FlaskApp
    - app.py
    - Face_recognition
        - detect_simple.py
```

Then use:

```
from Face_recognition import detect_simple
```

Comment: Im tried, but it return error: ImportError: No module named Face_recognition

Comment: Is that what your directory looks like?

Comment: Yes, but im find a problem, im create file test.py in folder FlaskApp, im run code from Face_recognition import detect_simple, it working. But run in file app.py not working.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the `__import__()` statement still? Don't use that for this approach. If the import statements are the same and you're sure you're running `app.py` from the same directory that it's in then I'm not sure I can help you.

Comment: Im run pipenv shell, and pipenv install Flask, it working, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Jab's answer: your `Face_recognition` directory must contain a (potentially empty) `__init__.py` file (with two leading *and* two trailing underscores) to be recognized by the import system.
 Once your tree looks like this:

```
FlaskApp
|_ app.py
|_ Face_detection/
   |_ __init__.py
   |_ detect_simple.py
```

You'll be able to do a

```
from Face_detection.detect_simple import <whatever>

# or
import Face_detection.detect_simple

# or
from Face_detecting import detect_simple
```

Keep in mind that the import system is case-sensitive.

On a separate note, please avoid using the `__import__` function in almost any case. Prefer the `import` statement if you're just importing stuff normally, or use `importlib.import_module` if you *have* to do programmatic imports (although this shouldn't be the default in most cases).

Comment: Im find a problem, im create file test.py in folder FlaskApp, im run code from Face_recognition import detect_simple, it working. But run in file app.py not working.

Comment: That's a separate question that you'll have to include details for.